# What is the convention to include supporting services in a project that uses docker?

Tags: git, project, docker

There are lots of articles and documentation for docker that describe how I can configure a web node profile. I find however that it's relatively light on describing how I might go on to include profiles for things like my database server, caching, workers and message queue services alongside.

If I'm trying to create an all-inclusive project with my Dockerfiles in source control, how am I supposed to structure things?

Not an exhaustive list, but such that:

- I can maybe spin up the entire cluster in one command
- All processes can communicate with each other
- I am placing Dockerfile(s?) in a meaningful location
- I can select and signal the correct environment to run in to my apps
- I correctly share my app's source code to the web node

Comment: My 2 cents. As you should know docker advocates to use one container per process, so you would have one container for your database service, one for your web application, etc. I think web apps should be configured with environment variables and in docker there is an option to pass a file with your environment variables, this way you can pass env vars for development, staging, production, etc. And lastly, in my experience it's better to use some service like [Fig](https://github.com/docker/fig) that handle your dockerfiles. Sorry I can't help you more.

Answer (score 0):

#### I can maybe spin up the entire cluster in one command

[fig](http://www.fig.sh/)

#### All processes can communicate with each other

You can link containers using:

```
docker run --link other-continer:ALIAS -it this-container
```

All exposed ports on linked container will be available to this container.
Environment variable [ALIAS]_PORT_[PORT]_TCP_ADDR and [ALIAS]_PORT_[PORT]_TCP_PORT will tell you where to connect to the other host.

#### I am placing Dockerfile(s?) in a meaningful location

No good answer here our other [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64639/discussion-between-usman-ismail-and-omega) is relevant. Place them each in their own folder, and then you can put them anywhere. They are not semantically linked to the source of your project.

#### I can select and signal the correct environment to run in to my apps

You can use:

```
docker run -e VAR_NAME=value ...
```

#### I correctly share my app's source code to the web node:

You can use the following command to pull in source into your docker container at build time.

```
ADD http://url-to-your-source/ /folder/in/container
```

### Putting it all together:

```
github.com/user/project/src/...

# Or each of these in their own github repo if you want to be super canonical
github.com/user/project/docker-files/base/Dockerfile
github.com/user/project/docker-files/web/Dockerfile
github.com/user/project/docker-files/db/Dockerfile
github.com/user/project/docker-files/worker/Dockerfile

github.com/user/project/fig.yml
```

Your fig.yml would look something like

```
base:
  build: ./docker-files/base/
web:
  build: ./docker-files/web/
  command: Something
  links:
   - db
   - worker
  ports:
   - "8000:8000"
db:
  build: ./docker-files/db/
  expose:
   - "3306"
worker:
  build: ./docker-files/worker/
  expose:
   - "9000"
```

The entry point in the web node will be a script which looks up the environment variables below and sets up configuration files accordingly before starting your web server. This should be done in script not in Dockerfile as the linkages are created at run time not build time.

```
DB_PORT\_3306\_TCP_ADDR
DB_PORT\_3306\_TCP_PORT
WORKER_PORT\_9000\_TCP_ADDR
WORKER_PORT\_9000\_TCP_PORT
```

You should use the following command to pull source into your docker container (if you need source) otherwise you can just pull built artifact from somewhere as well.

```
ADD https://api.github.com/repos/user/projects/tarball /tmp/src
```

To avoid repetition add common steps such as maybe installing php or pulling source into the base docker container and then use from: base in your other containers to pull in image with those steps already performed.

You can then do:

```
fig build
fig start
```